# How many methods for smoothing an unsmoothed function?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-optimization, subgradient

Which is the simplest one? For example, we smooth $f(x)=|x|$ to 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{x^2}{\epsilon}+\frac{\epsilon}{2} & |x| \le \epsilon\\
                    |x| & |x|\ge epsilon \end{cases}$$

Comment: What do you mean by smoothing?

Comment: like $|x|$, We could change its value around 0, make it is smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In convex analysis, maybe the most natural or best way to smooth a convex function $f$ is to use the Moreau-Yosida regularization of $f$:

\begin{equation}
f^{(\mu)}(x) = \inf_u f(u) + \frac{1}{2\mu} \|u - x\|_2^2.
\end{equation}

This is discussed in lecture 15 ("Multiplier methods") of Vandenberghe's 236c [notes](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee236c.html).

If $f(x) = |x|$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, and $\mu > 0$, then
\begin{equation}
f^{(\mu)}(x) =
\begin{cases}
|x| - \frac{\mu}{2} \quad \text{if } |x| > \mu \\
\frac{x^2}{2\mu} \quad \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 3):

The simplest (and only) method I know is [mollification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier).

Comment: +1.  And though it is not compactly supported, the heat kernel can yield similar results by [playing the rolw of a mollifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Homogeneous_heat_equation). In the case of the absolute value function this leads to smoothings like $$\frac{e^{-25 x^2}}{5 \sqrt{\pi}}+x \operatorname{erf}(5x)$$ or simply $$x \operatorname{erf}(5x)$$ if you prefer.

Comment: In convex analysis we also have the Moreau-Yosida regularization of $f$, which is the "infimal convolution" of $f$ with the convex function $\frac{1}{2\mu} \|x\|_2^2$.  In other words, $f^{(\mu)}(x) = \inf_u f(u) + \frac{1}{2\mu} \|u-x\|_2^2$.